# Need a logistic like function with y=0 at x=0

Tags: functions, logistic-regression

A logistic curve:

$$y=\frac{50}{1+e^{-k(x-10)}}$$

fits my exp data very well (having a maximum value 50, having a good trend). However, I hope it can return to zero when $x=0$. Is there an alternative function better than logistic function.

Comment: What properties do you want? Continuity?

Comment: @avid19 Yes, I hope so. Is it possible to further drive down the $y$ value at the beginning? i.e., around $x=0$?

Answer (score 1):

Logistic functions are a special case within the Richards family of asymptotic growth models with inflection points. Considerable attention has been given to this family with [Tjørve and Tjørve (2017)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ecolmodel.2017.05.008) unifying Richards models to two equivalent forms. Merging notations,

$$y = A \left(1 + \left(\left(\frac{y_0}{A}\right)^{1-d} - 1\right) \exp\left(\frac{-k_U \cdot x}{d^{\frac{d}{1 - d}}}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{1 - d}}$$

where $A$ is the upper asymptote, $y_0$ the y intercept, $d$ controls inflection, and $k_U$ the relative maximum growth rate. In this case the choices $y_0 = 0$ and $A = 50$ are desired, leaving $k_U$ and $0 < d \le 1$ free for fitting. ($d = 1$ is the unified Gompertz, a special case, and $y_0 = 0$ results in $d > 1$ dividing by zero. $d < 0$ typically yields $y \in \mathbb{C}$.)

While unified logistic models have $d = -1$ it seems more likely $d$ in the vicinity of 0.85 would be of interest here, along with a $k_U$ of perhaps something like 0.1. However, it's been seven years since this question was asked.

[image: unified Richards, d = 0.85]

Answer (score 0):

How about

$$\tilde{y}(x)=y(x)-y(0)e^{-x}$$

You have $\tilde{y}(0)=0$, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \tilde{y}(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} y(x)$. You have continuity, and for $x$ being somewhat big enough, it behaves just like $y(x)$.

Comment: The trend is changed by doing so. The logistic growth has a property that I need, it is bending downward (lower-right) at the beginning and then bending upward (upper-left) after a certain point.