# Is there a sigmoid-like function that is zero when $x\to 0$ and 1 when $x\to\infty$?

Tags: functions

Is there a *sigmoid-like* function such that
$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 1$$

[image]

Comment: What does it mean to be "sigmoid-like" other than the limit properties you mentioned?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri meaning that around $x~0$ the increase in $f$ will be slow, but then it will jump up quickly. Then it will converge to 1 infinitely slowly, just like the sigmoid function.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri i.e without the axes, the plot of the function should look like a sigmoid function.

Comment: How slow does it has to be near $x=0$ -- asymptotically $x^n$?  $e^{-1/x}$?  $e^{-1/x^n}$?

Comment: (arctan(10ln(x)-10)+pi/2)/pi

Comment: @user10354138 ideally $e^{-1/x^2}$

Comment: Arctan(x) *2/pi

Comment: The integral of a probability density defined for $x\ge 0$ from 0 to x.

Comment: So what's wrong with $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$?

Comment: @TonyK It is not symmetric in its asymptotic behaviour in $x\to 0$ and $x\to \infty$ limit

Comment: What can you mean by that?

Comment: @TonyK it converges to 1 much slower than it converges to zero

Comment: Well of course it does! How could it possibly not?

Comment: @TonyK well, that is not a property that I want to have

Comment: If you think about it a bit, you will see that it's an impossible dream. Unless you want $f(x)$ to actually _reach_ $1$ at some point.

Comment: This question is, within a multiplicative constant, the same as [this older one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1428935/need-a-logistic-like-function-with-y-0-at-x-0/) that's been answered.